# How to insert data using db link

Tags: oracle, dblink

I want to Insert data to another Database
A server : Oracle 19c
B server : Tibero7

I made DB Link and checked it works well.
So I Insert into Tibero Oracle data using db link like

```
INSERT INTO BOTH_TEST@TBR_LINK (ID, KOR_NAME, ENG_NAME) SELECT ID, KOR_NM, ENG_NM FROM COMET_MIG.TEST_
```

But It doesn't work with ORA-02025: all tables in the SQL statement must be at the remote database.
Is there any way to insert data to another DB?

Comment: [ORA-02025](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96525/e1500.htm#1003914)
**Cause**: A SQL statement referenced tables from multiple databases, and one or more of the remote databases are not Oracle Servers.

**Action**: Remote updates can be performed only if all databases in the SQL statement are Oracle Servers. Update the earlier version databases in a separate statement

Comment: You may try to trigger the pull of the data at the the remote site instead of push mechanism